# Working with data returned as a Complex Array

Tags: c#, object, multidimensional-array, arraylist

Please bear with me if my terminology is incorrect.

I'm attempting to extract data from an object. The object has a complex array which consist of rows and 6 columns per row.

I need to access the very last row in the array so I'm using .Count. The problem is a can't access the columns within the row. Here is the code:

```
           var weight = USBHIDDRIVER.USBInterface.usbBuffer;
           var cnt = weight.Count;
           Debug.WriteLine(weight[cnt][4]);

USBHIDDRIVER.USBInterface.usbBuffer; contains data in the following format:

ROW [0] - COL [0] = 3
          COL [1] = 4
          COL [2] = 3
          COL [3] = 255
          COL [4] = 6
          COL [5] = 0
Row [1] - COL [0] = 3
          COL [1] = 4
          COL [2] = 3
          COL [3] = 255
          COL [4] = 6
          COL [5] = 0
```

etc, etc.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exception? Also did you make sure count is greater than 0?

Comment: Use `cnt - 1` or `var cnt = weight.Count - 1;`

Comment: @Neo the error I receive is "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object"

Comment: @EBrown the count is good, I'm receiving the correct value that represents the rows.

Comment: And have you *verified* that `weight` is a 2-dimensional array?

Comment: What is the actual type of USBHIDDRIVER.USBInterface.usbBuffer?

Comment: Are you sure that the 2d array you're getting is weight[ ][ ], or is it weight[ , ]?  weight[ ][ ] is actually meant for a jagged array, where weight[ , ] would be an actual 2d array.

Comment: @Neo USBHIDDRIVER.USBInterface.usbBuffer is an object which is where I believe I'm having my problem.

Comment: @Neo USBHIDDRIVER.USBInterface.usbBuffer.GetType() returns USBHIDDRIVER.List.ListWithEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because accessing a zero based List here, so you should be indexing the last field of the array using `Count - 1`.

`USBHIDDRIVER.USBInterface.usbBuffer` is an `ArrayList`, so it's elements are of type `object`. To have access to the elements of type `byte[]` that were added to this list, you will have to typecast the elements to `byte[]`:

```
Debug.WriteLine(((byte[])weight[cnt-1])[4]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter, the problem is I'm receiving the following error in VS "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object" so I can't compile. If I remove the [4] then I can run my script but then I can't access the value of [4] in the column.

Comment: Just had a look at USBHIDDRIVER and updated my answer.

Comment: that did the trick, lead the group down the wrong path by not knowing the Type of object. Thank you for researching.